# Create GIF from Screenshots

Tags: command-line, script, screen-capture

**Hello everyone,**

I need to create a program to take a set of screenshots and converrt them into a GIF.

I've currently got this code in **Shell** which works, but the output is quite choppy.

```
cd "~/.ScreenRecorderCache"

echo "Ensuring cache is clear..."
rm -rf ~/.ScreenRecorderCache/*.png

echo "This program currently only records for five seconds, and then makes a GIF."
echo "Your GIF will be saved to your Desktop."
echo "Starting to take screenshots..."
for x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
do
  screencapture -b ~/.ScreenRecorderCache/SC-No$x.png
  echo "Taken screenshot number $x"
done

echo "Making the GIF - this may take some time depending on the length of your recording..."

gm convert -set delay 4 ~/.ScreenRecorderCache/*.png ~/Desktop/ScreenRecording.gif

echo "Your GIF has been made, and saved to your desktop!"

echo "Clearing cache and exiting..."
rm -rf ~/.ScreenRecorderCache/*.png
```

This code makes a five second GIF at thirty frames a second = **5 seconds x 30 frames = 150 frames to capture**.

I get that this is a little weird, but I need a solution somehow...!

I'm happy to do this in almost any language, but it has to be easily packageable into a distributable **.app** executable.

I'm also going to create a **.pkg** installer that installs the app and anything else it requires, plus the hidden folder in the user's home directory.

**If anyone has a solution, I'd be extremely grateful. I get that this is a pretty niche issue.**

**Thank you all so much in advance, and I hope you're all doing well during these tough times.**

Comment: Might be easier to record a video and convert this. Also, `man seq`.

Comment: `... for x in {1..150} ...`!!

Comment: There is a free app that does this for you. its called Adaptor and you can read about it or download it from here. https://macroplant.com/adapter.  It does animated GIFS from images and easily does batch conversions.

Comment: Also an app called GIPHY CAPTURE on the App Store, which makes GIFs directly from screen capture.